# Differences between REF and RREF

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Can we say that a system in REF has no solution if the last column of the augmented matrix contains a leading entry. I am a little confused about REF and RREF. Do we need to use RREF to tell whether the system has a solution? OR just REF is enough to tell whether the system has no solutions, infinitely many solutions or one unique solution.

Comment: Glossary (should have been included: I used Google): (R)REF= (reduced) row echelon form. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form

Answer (score 0):

REF is enough. RREF will give you the solutions if any, but REF is enough since the necessary and sufficient condition to have no solution is that the rank of the augmented matrix is greater than the rank of the matrix of the linear system.

Comment: How do you define the augmented matrix and the matrix of the linear system? Suppose we have [A|b]?

Comment: The matrix of the linear system is the matrix of the left-hand side homogeneous equations. In your example, it's $[A]$, and the augmented matrix is $[A\mid b]$. The rank of the augmented matrix is either rank$(A)$ or rank$(A)+1$.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot!